# Why is Google Maps API refusing to plot my Polyline array?

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3, geocode, google-geocoder

I think the problem has something to do with how I am building the path array for my Polyline but there has to be a way to do it like this. The goal is to create an array of Geocode locations from an array input fields named "address[]". I've gotten the Polyline to work by doing this:

```
// ARRAY
var linePath = [
new google.maps.LatLng(37.772323, -122.214897),
new google.maps.LatLng(21.291982, -157.821856),
new google.maps.LatLng(-18.142599, 178.431),
new google.maps.LatLng(-27.46758, 153.027892)
];

// console.log(linePath);
[P { Ia=37.772323, Ja=-122.21489700000001}, P { Ia=21.291982, Ja=-157.82185600000003}, P { Ia=-18.142599, Ja=178.43100000000004}, P { Ia=-27.46758, Ja=153.02789200000007}]
```

But when I try to create an array from an $.each statement, the array comes out differently and doesn't work. Here is the code I have written:

```
// ARRAY
$("input[name='submit']").click(function() {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    locations = new Array();
    $("input[name='address[]']").each(function() {
        geocoder.geocode({"address" : this.value }, function(results) {
            var addrLl = results[0].geometry.location;
            locations.push(addrLl);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: addrLl
            });
        });
    });

    var connect = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: locations,
        strokeColor: "#FF0000",
        strokeOpacity: 1.
    });
    connect.setMap(map);
    return false;
});

// console.log(locations);
[]
   [+] 0    P { Ia=41.8843266, Ja=-78.79295300000001}
   [+] 1    P { Ia=35.9614504, Ja=-79.04755590000002}
```

Any ideas what I should do?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "the array comes out differently"?  How is it coming out?  And how is that different from what you expected?

Comment: Sorry about not being more clear. I've edited the post and added the console outputs.

Comment: Ah, that helps a lot.  Do those + signs on the left mean that you could expand something to show more info?

Comment: Yes they do. To get an idea of what the results[0] array contains you can visit this website: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#JSON

Comment: What's your console output if, instead of `locations.push(addrLl);` you do `locations.push(addrLl.toString());` in the second example?

Comment: I copy and paste your code, do some minimal tweaking to get it to work, and I don't get these results.  I get the expected results instead.  Are you still having this problem? If not, do you have any idea what you did to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Geocoding is asynchronous - your results may not have returned by the time you construct the polyline so will not be included in the polyline. When the geocoder does return (possibly up to a second later) the point will be added to locations, so you will see it when you console log the array, but the Polyline will not know about it.

Luckily the Maps API has a neat solution to this which is to use an MVCArray. Replace:

```
locations = new Array();
```

with

```
locations = new MVCArray();
```

Now, each time you add a new point to the array, even if it is after you have already created the polygon, the polygon will be notified and will update to include the point.